# Range of cells into single cell with carriage return

Tags: excel, vba

I am working through my first VBA book and would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction. How would I transfer a range of rows into a single cell with carriage returns? I would then like to repeat this action for all ranges in the column.

I think I need to:

- find the first cell with a value in the column
- verify that the next row is not empty
- find the last cell in the range
- perform "the operation" on the range

[image: Start]

[image]

Comment: You can loop through the range and store the cell contents in a Variable separated with `vbNewline` and then in the end write to the cell?

Comment: Thank you. Is the procedure above the best way of defining the ranges? There should be a few thousand of them separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comments. here is a very simple way to achieve what you want.

```
Option Explicit

'~~> You can use any delimiter that you want
Const Delim = vbNewLine

Sub Sample()
    Dim rngInput As Range, rngOutput As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rngInput = Range("A1:A5") '<~~ Input Range
    Set rngOutput = Range("B1")   '<~~ Output Range

    Concatenate rngInput, rngOutput

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Concatenate(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim strOutPut As String

    For Each cl In rng1
        If strOutPut = "" Then
            strOutPut = cl.Value
        Else
            strOutPut = strOutPut & Delim & cl.Value
        End If
    Next

    rng2.Value = strOutPut
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I alter this to replace the first cell of the original range with the Concatenated Range rather than putting it in b1?

Comment: By changing `Concatenate rngInput, rngOutput` to `Concatenate rngInput, rngInput.Cells(1, 1)` :)

Comment: Or you can change `Set rngOutput = Range("B1")` to `Set rngOutput = rngInput.Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: That works. Now I just need to find all of the ranges rather than declaring A1:A5. Then I need to sit down with the book and figure out all of the pieces. I may have asked the question too early for me to appreciate the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. :) You can always use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row` for example to find the lastRow say in Col A and then you can dynamically construct your range :)

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of a worksheet-level code, the following will work. Column 2 is hard-coded, so you might want to pass in a value or otherwise modify it to fit your needs.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Me.Columns(2)

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

' Find first row with non-empty cell; bail out if first 100 rows empty
If IsEmpty(Me.Cells(1, 2)) Then
    Do
        row = row + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Me.Cells(row, 2)) = False Or row = 101
End If

If row = 101 Then Exit Sub

' We'll need to know the top row of the range later, so hold the value
Dim firstRow As Integer
firstRow = row

' Combine the text from each subsequent row until an empty cell is encountered
Dim result As String
Do
    If result <> "" Then result = result & vbNewLine
    result = result & Me.Cells(row, 2).Text
    row = row + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Me.Cells(row, 2))

' Clear the content of the range
Set rng = Me.Range(Me.Cells(firstRow, 2), Me.Cells(row, 2))
rng.Clear

' Set the text in the first cell
Me.Cells(firstRow, 2).Value2 = result
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. I added sub tester() to the top and replaced Me with ActiveSheet.  Right?  Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed that this works for the first range in column 2, but not for the others. It is certainly enough to point me in the right direction though.  Thanks again.

Comment: @adayzdone Sorry, I don't see that need in the question. Would you want the next set to be in the next cell down from the first, or at the topmost cell of the range?

Comment: My mistake, I will update the question. The next range would start at the topmost cell of the range. There might be one empty or 20, in between ranges.